# Html/Flash Hybrid Website: rollover issues in Firefox 3

Tags: html, flash, sifr, swfobject

I am currently developing a PHP website that has a lot of Flash components. On each page there are one or more custom Flash components embedded with swfObject, as well as sIFR navigation.

Every so often, ALL of the Flash objects on the page become unresponsive to the mouse (no hand pointer). So far I have found it happening only in Firefox 3.5.3 on Mac. I am using CSS to position everything with a specific stacking order to get around the bounding-box overlap issue - for example, the main navigation overlaps the top right corner of a big Flash component.

It works fine most of the time, however, if I click through the pages enough times in Firefox 3 on Mac, eventually I cannot "roll over" any of the Flash elements.

Does anyone know why all the Flash objects in a PHP page would stop responding to the mouse, sIFR included?

[Here is the site](http://thestationatothellopark.com/test/index.php) if you want to give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually a combination of putting `wmode` (transparent or opaque) on the Flash movie, which itself is contained in a `float`ed element. Unfortunately it's a browser bug, but removing the `wmode` property should fix it.